# Appium: How to get adb logcat for multiple android devices

Tags: testng, appium

I have to execute my test on more then one device.
So how to get logcat for every device?

My current code is:

```
List logEntries = driver.manage().logs().get("logcat").getAll();
File logFile = new File(logPathWithFile);
PrintWriter log_file_writer = new PrintWriter(logFile);
for (LogEntry temp : logEntries) {
log_file_writer.println(temp);
}
log_file_writer.close();
```

This only creates one file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple devices attached to your system, you can get logs for specific device by following the below mentioned steps:

1.Get the device id of your device.
You can get this by running the command `adb devices` in your terminal.
2.Now use the following command:

```
adb -s serialNumberOfDevice logcat
```

This will give logs specific to the device whose serialNumber has been given in the adb command.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank you for your response but i want that log into one file and i have to send that file via mail through java mail API.
i am using https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/970 please check my code too.

Comment: adb -s serialNumberOfDevice logcat > logcat_dev_1.txt, repeat for devices 2...N and concatenate.
BUT from my experience using adb in parallel to appium will cause problems and introduce instability to your test system.

Comment: @rsf i don't want to do this manually like open terminal and write that command. so how can i do automation for the same.

Comment: look for your programming language equivalent of System command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set serialNumberOfDevice to udid in capabilities.

- http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/

  - udid - Unique device identifier of the connected physical device